# PostgreSQL - Possible to Query Multiple Rows to Determine Single, Defined Value?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

Working with a dataset like what follows - is it possible to query multiple columns to determine a pre-defined value?

For example, querying the data would return a status of either 'Complete' or 'Pending' depending on the status of each `eventId`, i.e., if all `eventId` status = 'Approved' - the event's status is 'Complete'. Otherwise, the event's status will be 'Pending'.

`eventId` = `1` has three status - Draft, Draft, Submitted - Status = Pending.
`eventId` = `2` has two status - Approved, Approved - Status = Complete.
`eventId` = `3` has one status - Submitted - Status = Pending.
`eventId` = `4` has two status - Draft, Draft - Status = Pending.

```
| activityId    | eventId       | status    |
| ------------- | ------------- | -----     |
| 1             | 1             | Draft     |
| 2             | 1             | Draft     |
| 3             | 1             | Submitted |
| 4             | 2             | Approved  |
| 5             | 2             | Approved  |
| 6             | 3             | Submitted |
| 7             | 4             | Draft     |
| 8             | 4             | Draft     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each event you can count rows where status is 'Approved' and compare this with the number of all rows:

```
select 
    eventid, 
    string_agg(status, ', ') as statuses, 
    case when count(*) = count(case status when 'Approved' then 1 end) 
        then 'Complete'
        else 'Pending' end as event_status
from my_table
group by 1
order by 1

 eventid |        statuses         | event_status 
---------+-------------------------+--------------
       1 | Draft, Draft, Submitted | Pending
       2 | Approved, Approved      | Complete
       3 | Submitted               | Pending
       4 | Draft, Draft            | Pending
(4 rows)
```

You can remove the second column of course if you do not need it.

The more elegant version with a [boolean aggregate:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
select 
    eventid, 
    string_agg(status, ', ') statuses, 
    case when bool_and(status = 'Approved')
        then 'Complete'
        else 'Pending' end as event_status
from my_table
group by 1
order by 1
```